# imported less is undefined

Tags: typescript, webpack, less

In the `src/pages/login/index.tsx`, the imported `styles` is undefined. But the `src/pages/login/index.less` actually exists.

The `index.tsx` :

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from './index.less';

const Login: React.FC = () => {
  console.log(styles); // undefined

  return <div className={styles.login}>Login Page</div>
```

The index.less:

```
.login {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

Could someone tell me how to solve it?

---

I use webpack as the build tool, here's my webpack config:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const CssMinimizerPlugin = require('css-minimizer-webpack-plugin');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');

const rootDir = process.cwd();

function resolve(dir) {
  return path.join(__dirname, '.', dir);
}

module.exports = {
  entry: path.resolve(rootDir, 'src/index.tsx'),
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(rootDir, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.[contenthash:8].js',
    clean: true
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(jsx|js)$/,
        use: 'babel-loader',
        include: path.resolve(rootDir, 'src'),
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              modules: false
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/i,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              modules: false
            }
          },
          'postcss-loader',
          {
            loader: 'less-loader',
            options: {
              lessOptions: {
                javascriptEnabled: true
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              modules: false
            }
          },
          'sass-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|jpeg|webp|svg|eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
        type: 'asset'
      },
      {
        test: /.(ts|tsx)$/, 
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'thread-loader',
            options: {}
          },
          'babel-loader',
          {
            loader: 'ts-loader',
            options: {
              happyPackMode: true,
              transpileOnly: true
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
    alias: {
      '@': resolve('src')
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.resolve(rootDir, 'public/index.html'),
      inject: 'body',
      scriptLoading: 'blocking'
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: 'css/[name].css'
    }),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin({
      patterns: [
        {
          from: '*.js',
          context: path.resolve(rootDir, 'public/js'),
          to: path.resolve(rootDir, 'dist/js')
        }
      ]
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: 'css/[name].css'
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.SplitChunksPlugin()
  ],
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: 'all' 
    },
    minimizer: [new CssMinimizerPlugin()]
  }
};
```

Comment: This depends on how your build pipeline is set up, can you show the relevant configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `modules: false` to `modules: true` for less.

```
{
        test: /\.less$/i,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              modules: true
            }
          },
          'postcss-loader',
          {
            loader: 'less-loader',
            options: {
              lessOptions: {
                javascriptEnabled: true
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
```